# DHTMLX Freeze grid is not working in IE

Tags: dhtmlx

When freeze applied to dhtmlxgrid the header repeating based on the split value.

Before applying split

```
code    desc          Qtytype    w1    w2
Part A  Part A desc   Demand     100  200
```

After apply split the grid looks like in IE

```
code    desc          Qtytype    code    desc    Qtytype  w1  w2
Part A  Part A desc   Demand     100     200      300     400 500
```

Kindly advise how to arrest the header repeat in IE.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SplitAt before init. And try to Load the Header and Detail dhtmlx ajax synchron call.,